# Submitting an array of jobs on SLURM

Tags: slurm

I am trying to submit an array of jobs on SLURM but the sleep command doesn't work as expected. I would like to launch a job every 10 seconds. However, this code waits 10 seconds to launch the whole array of jobs. How should I modify the following bash file?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# The name to show in queue lists for this job:
#SBATCH -J matlab.sh

# Number of desired cpus:
#SBATCH --cpus=1
#SBATCH --mem=8gb

# The time the job will be running:
#SBATCH --time=167:00:00

# To use GPUs you have to request them:
##SBATCH --gres=gpu:1

# If you need nodes with special features uncomment the desired constraint line:
##SBATCH --constraint=bigmem
#SBATCH --constraint=cal
##SBATCH --constraint=slim

# Set output and error files
#SBATCH --error=job.%J.err
#SBATCH --output=job.%J.out

# MAKE AN ARRAY JOB, SLURM_ARRAYID will take values from 1 to 100
#SARRAY --range=1-60

# To load some software (you can show the list with 'module avail'):
module load matlab

export from=400
export to=1000


export steps=60

mkdir  temp_${SLURM_ARRAYID}
cd temp_${SLURM_ARRAYID}
# the program to execute with its parameters:
matlab < ../SS.m  > output_temp_${SLURM_ARRAYID}.out
sleep 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

> A maximum number of simultaneously running tasks from the job array
>   may be specified using a "%" separator. For example "--array=0-15%4"
>   will limit the number of simultaneously running tasks from this job
>   array to 4.

So if you want to submit a job array of 60 jobs, but run only one job at a time, updating your submission script like this should to the trick

```
#SBATCH --array=1-60%1
```

Comment: Well, the idea is to not overload the job scheduler when submitting 60 jobs at the same time. However, I do want 60 jobs running at the same time (but not launched at the same time)

Comment: What if you `sleep $((SLURM_ARRAYID * 10))` **before** `srun` then ?

Comment: my bad, i was thinking of an other related question. `sleep` before invoking `matlab`. out of curiosity, what is the rationale for not starting the jobs at the same time ? at first glance, slurm should be able to handle that.

Comment: The sentence "MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering." outputs and nothing else happens. Some jobs display this message while other begin to run, so I thought it was a problem with the scheduler

Comment: that looks unrelated to the scheduler. what if you `matlab -nosoftwareopengl` ?

Comment: yeah, what I mean is that some jobs stop running. With your trick, the whole array of jobs seems to work, thanks!